# auto_ptr question in c++

Tags: c++

I am new here.
I am also new on C++
So here is the class and function i wrote.But i got the compiler error
My class:

```
class fooPlayer
{
public:
       void fooPlayerfunc(){}//doing something here
       char askYesNo(std::string question);
};

class fooPlayerFactory
{
public:
   virtual std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer> MakePlayerX() const;
   virtual std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer> MakePlayerO() const;
private:
   std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer> MakePlayer(char letter) const;
   std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer> my_player;

};
```

Implement my class:

```
auto_ptr<fooPlayer> fooPlayerFactory:: MakePlayer(char letter) const
{
       my_player->fooPlayerfunc();
       return my_player;
}

auto_ptr<fooPlayer> fooPlayerFactory::MakePlayerX() const
{
      char go_first = my_player->askYesNo("Do you require the first move?");
      MakePlayer(go_first);
      return my_player;
}

auto_ptr<fooPlayer> fooPlayerFactory::MakePlayerO() const
{
    return my_player;
}
```

My main() function here:

```
int main()
{
          fooPlayerFactory factory;
          factory.MakePlayerX();
          factory.MakePlayerO();
}
```

I got the error:
error C2558: class 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'

I do not know how to change it even after reading the document on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xcz0y39(VS.71).aspx) link:

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the error is that you are calling the copy constructor of auto_ptr my_player in fooPlayerFactory::MakePlayerO() which is a const method.  That means that is cannot modify its members.

However the copy constructor of auto_ptr DOES modify the right hand side so returning my_player trys to change its pointer to 0 (NULL), while assigning the original pointer to the auto_ptr in the return value.

The signature of the copy constuctor is

```
auto_ptr<T>::auto_ptr<T>(auto_ptr<T> & rhs)
```

not

```
auto_ptr<T>::auto_ptr<T>(const auto_ptr<T> & rhs)
```

The copy constructor of auto_ptr assigns ownership of the pointer to the left hand side, the right hand side then holds nothing.

I don't think you want to use auto_ptr here, you probably want boost::smart_ptr

It looks like you have mixed up two uses for auto_ptr

The first is as poor man's boost::scoped_ptr.  This is to manage a single instance of a pointer in a class, the class manages the life time of the pointer.  In this case you don't normally return this pointer outside your class (you can it is legal, but boost::smart_ptr / boost::weak_ptr would be better so clients can participate the life time of the pointer)

The second is its main purpose which is to return a newly created pointer to the caller of a function in an exception safe way.

eg

```
auto_ptr<T> foo() {
    return new T;
}

void bar() {
    auto_ptr<T> t = foo();
}
```

As I said I think you have mixed these two uses auto_ptr is a subtle beast you should read the auto_ptr docs carefully.  It is also covered very well in [Effective STL by Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629).

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
auto_ptr<fooPlayer> fooPlayerFactory:: MakePlayer(char letter) const
{
       my_player->fooPlayerfunc();
       return my_player;
}
```

This is a const function, but `fooPlayerfunc` is not const - my compiler reports this error rather than the one you say you are getting. Are you posting the real code?

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: He didn't say exactly where the error he got was but I expect it was on the return statement of each function which calls the copy constructor.

However your answer hilighted it to me +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you actually want to constructing dynamic objects here.
A factory object creates and returns an object it normally does not keep a reference to it after creation (unless you are sharing it), and I don't actually see anywhere that you are creating the player.

If you only ever create one player internally in your (fooPlayerFactory). Then create an object and return references to it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: in response to the comment (which is correct, my bad), I left only the advice part.

Best practice is to have the factory methods just return a plain old pointer to the underlying object, and let the caller decide how to manage ownership (auto_ptr, scoped_ptr, or whatever).

Comment: Absolutely Disagree. You should never be passing RAW pointers around There is just too much chance they will be dropped. If you are not sure return a std::auto_ptr<>. A shared_ptr<> has a constructor that accepts an auto_ptr<> and takes ownership from the returned auto_prt<>

Comment: @martin - I for one disagree with you - I would rather the policy of dynamic memory management be decided by the user of the factory.

Comment: I am with Martin on this.  You must use auto_ptr or similar to preserve exception safety.  However the use of auto_ptr in the case above looks bogus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anywhere you construct `my_player`, so I have a feeling that some of the code is missing.  Specifically, I think your constructor has this line:

```
my_player = new fooPlayer()
```

A `fooPlayer` object is not quite the same thing as an `auto_ptr<fooPlayer>` object, and `auto_ptr` is intentionally designed to prevent assigning from one to the other because, frankly, the alternative is worse.  For the details, look up (1) conversion constructors, (2) the `explicit` keyword, and (3) copy constructors and destructive copy semantics.

You should change the constructor to either:

```
class fooPlayerFactory {
    public:
    fooPlayerFactory()
    {
        my_player = std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer>(new fooPlayer());
    }
```

Or (using a member initializer list):

```
class fooPlayerFactory {
    public:
    fooPlayerFactory() : my_player(std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer>(new fooPlayer()) { }
```

The solution isn't pretty but, like I said, the alternative is worse due to some really arcane details.

---

As a bit of advice, though, you're making life harder than it needs to be; and may in fact be causing strange bugs.  `auto_ptr` exists to manage the lifetime of an object, but the only reason  you need to worry about the lifetime of `my_player` is that you've allocated it with `new`.  But there's no need to call `new`, and in fact there's no need to keep `my_player`.  And unless `fooPlayerFactory` is meant to be the base class for some other factory, there's no need to mark functions `virtual`.

Originally I thought you could get away with simply returning copies of the `my_player` object, but there's a problem:  before returning `my_player` from `MakePlayer()` you call a  method on it, and I assume that method changes the internal state of `my_player`.  Further calls to `MakePlayer()` will change the state again, and I think you're going to eventually have `my_player` in the wrong state.  Instead, return a different `fooPlayer` object with each request.  Don't do memory management, just promise to construct the object.  That way the user can decide on memory allocation:

```
fooPlayerFaclotry factory;
fooPlayer on_stack = factory.MakePlayerX();
fooPlayer* on_heap_raw_pointer = new fooPlayer(factory.MakePlayerO());
std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer> on_heap_managed_scope
                         = std::auto_ptr<fooPlayer>(factory.MakePlayerX());
```

I would change `fooPlayerFactory` to look like this:

```
class fooPlayerFactory
{
private:
   fooPlayer MakePlayer(const char letter) const
   {
       fooPlayer result;
       result.fooPlayerfunc();
       return result;
   }

public:
   fooPlayer* MakePlayerX() const
   {
       char go_first = askYesNo("Do you require the first move?");
       return MakePlayer(go_first);
   }

   fooPlayer MakePlayerO() const
   {
       return fooPlayer();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your code is buggy, any class that implements virtual methods should have a virtual destructor.